# Java object locking: Deadlock when calling other methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock

If I use synchronize(this) in two methods and one calls the other, will I get stuck in a deadlock situation or will it work because the thread already owns the lock?

Picture the class below:

```
public class Test {
  public void foo() {
    synchronize(this) {
      bar();
    }
  }

  public void bar() {
    synchronize(this) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are two methods foo and bar, which both rely on synchronization.

When calling foo(), a lock will be obtained on (this); will bar try to do the same when called by foo (and thus causing a deadlock) or will it realize that the lock has already been obtained by the same thread?

Hope my explanation is more or less clear ;-)

Comment: Why do you do synchronization on this? Are there other methods in your class? You can use synchornized as a keyword on methods.

Comment: Colin, I was creating a Cache that internally handles expiration of the cached items by using two maps, one for the data and one for the corresponding expiration timestamps. Therefore neither synchronizing on a method nor using synchronized maps would have done the job, as both maps are manipulated by many methods and need to be in sync at any time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `synchronized` block is reentrant (in fact, Java monitors are reentrant, to be perfectly clear), thus no deadlock can happen in your situation.

According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread.
>   But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns.

Answer (score 3):

If thread holds lock of object it can enter to other synchronized blocks based on that lock object.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) you can read that

"...thread *can* acquire a lock that it already owns. Allowing a thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables *reentrant synchronization*. This describes a situation where synchronized code, directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block."

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful of though is if:

```
Thread A has the lock in foo() and needs to call bar()

and Thread B has the lock in bar() while needing to call foo()
```

Comment: I agree in general, but this couldn't happen when both threads synchronize on the same object - (this) in this case

Comment: Yeah, I should have been a little clearer. I was just describing a situation that would lead to a deadlock.